# How to make protocol exportable from a swift library without making it public?

Tags: swift

in my swift library I have a simple protocol like this:

```swift
    protocol DebugPrintable {
        func debug() -> String
    }
```

I would like to export it so that users of the library can refer to the protocol, but that would turn it into a public protocol:

```swift
    public protocol DebugPrintable {
        func debug() -> String
    }
```

... which forces all uses of protocol to be public - which is unnecessary.

Can I somehow make the *protocol* public (so that it is exported from library) but not make it force all declared properties to be public?

Comment: "which forces all uses of protocol to be public" What do you mean by this? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Sweeper I mean that when I make a protocol public (to allow users of library to use it), the protocol then forces its functions to be public - so I can't borrow the `DebugPrintable` protocol for a non-public use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here from documentation

> You can’t set a protocol requirement to a different access level than
> the protocol it supports. This ensures that all of the protocol’s
> requirements will be visible on any type that adopts the protocol.

> If you define a public protocol, the protocol’s requirements require a public access level for those requirements when they’re implemented. This behavior is different from other types, where a public type definition implies an access level of internal for the type’s members.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

I think you should move your protected properties to another protocol to satisfy above thing.

Comment: Thank you for a quote, it seems that this isn't possible then.